# how can i add a incremental date id to my logic? mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

This seems really simple but i am unsure how to do it in mysql. i have a table of status changes of trades. what i would like to do is for each trade find the max date and therefore it's status in a given month. however i would like to count this trade for that month of the following month (the 1st), how can i do this in mysql?

i have below:

```
SELECT Trade_id,
        max(Status_DateTime),
        DATE_FORMAT(Status_DateTime,'%Y%m') monthyear,
        DATE_ADD(DATE_FORMAT(Status_DateTime,'%Y%m'), interval 1 month)  as MonthYear_increment
FROM tabletrades
WHERE trade_status in ('open','partial','partial01') 
and Traade_id in('1234') 
group by Trade_id, 
    DATE_FORMAT(Status_DateTime,'%Y%m'),
    DATE_ADD(DATE_FORMAT(Status_DateTime,'%Y%m'), interval 1 month),
```

this does not really give me what i want though.. as the MonthYear_increment is null? i need this column as i need to be able to count my trade as the following 1st of the month.

how can i do this so that i get the following month of year as a column *and* i get this in the format year-month-day where day is 01. at present the date is 202005, i would ideally like 1st included too

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . You can get the last value for a month using `row_number()` and then add a month:

```
SELECT YEAR(status_datetime + interval 1 month),
       MONTH(status_datetime + interval 1 month),
       t.tradeid, t.status
FROM (SELECT t.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY year(Status_DateTime), month(Status_DateTime) ORDER BY Status_DateTime desc) as seqnum
      FROM tabletrades
      WHERE trade_status in ('open','partial','partial01')  AND
            Traade_id in ('1234') 
     ) t
WHERE seqnum = 1
```

Comment: This does not work, sql syntax error: "select" is not valid at this position for this server version' expecting '(' with.. i am using mysql workbench

Comment: @Maths12 . . . `row_number()` is available starting in MySQL 8.